# Feeding data from a CSV in to a PHP (Magento) object as a means of "importing" orders

Tags: php, magento, csv, object

I'm trying to programmatically import order data from an old point of sale system in to Magento using Magento's order object. The data coming out of the old point of sale system is in .CSV format.

So for example, if I have a .CSV that looks like this:

```
Email        ||     Firstname    ||    Lastname ||    GroupID
---------------------------------------------------------------
abc@abc.com  ||     John         ||    Smith    ||    General
```

How would I feed it in to, say, this part of Magento's order object?

```
// set Customer data
$order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
  ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
  ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
  ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
  ->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
  ->setCustomer($customer);
```

I know there's a lot more to Mage's order object than that, but this is simply for the sake of fleshing out the .CSV -> PHP object part. I know how to read a .CSV into an array using PHP - no prob, but I'm still pretty weak when it comes to dealing with objects and I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how to approach this. I've googled around and found other people using Mage's order object for various order uploading tasks, but nothing regarding how to pull that order data from a .CSV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this process is not a cake walk for the simple reason that unlike other functionality of Magento you cannot just call up a getModel() for Order and load an instance of order. Placing order programmatically is much more complex.

TO create a Magento order you will require much more information then just the Email, First Name, Last Name and Group Id. You will need information such as Billing Addresses,Shipping Addresses, Payment Methods, Product Information etc. In case you are not having these information, your first step would be to start gathering this information from the old system or to find a good replacement for the information. Then you can write your scripts which can pull data from csv and push it to Magento. We had done it earlier(a couple of years back on Magento 1.6.1. Due confidentiality issues (I was not the one writing code for this and this also is part of a paid magento extension) it would not be possible for me to share the actual code, but I can share with you the code that we were using for the CSV adapter to create the order.

Use this link for the code http://munjalmunshi.info/import_order.pdf

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is:

1) First your CSV file to upload it to your database.(Create a table with that).It would be easier to handle your data.

2) Use a while loop to go through each line of your table.Each line would be an individual order.

3) Use each row to set for example the customer name,quantity,address and etc.

Follow that [tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/)  to see how you can make an order programmatically with magento:

Hope it helps,
Cheers